# Why isnt my ng-model updating?

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that I have created.  There is a text box and I am trying to update the count of characters in the box.  First of all here is the html where my directive is declared.

```
<div chat-container encounter="selectedEncounter" ng-model="count"></div>
```

Here is my directive.

```
angular.module('clinicalApp').directive('chatContainer', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      encounter: '=',
      ngModel: '='
    },

    controller: 'EncounterCtrl',

    templateUrl: 'views/chat.container.html',

    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      var chatbox = elem.find('textarea');
      chatbox.bind('keyup',function() {
        scope.updateCount();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

In my template is a `{{count}}` that I want to be updated.

In my controller I have a function that I is called in the `bind` that updates the count.  Here is the function in my controller.

```
  $scope.updateCount = function() {
    $scope.count = 350;
  };
```

When this function is hit in my controller it does not update the count in my directive.  How do I make this work?

Even better, how do I make the directive update the count?  I thought the 2-way binding would take care of this, but it isnt.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was trying to update the wrong attribute in the template.  If you look above I was trying to update `{{count}}` and I needed to update `{{ngModel}}`.

Comment: I bet you'd rather go the other way, use count in your scope definition.  Rather than injecting `ngModel` which could easily be confused with the `ngModel` angular directive.

Comment: That is exactly what I did when I realized it was just another variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to notify angular that you updated a value:

```
$scope.updateCount = function() {
    $scope.$apply( function() {
       $scope.count = 350;
    });
};
```